# Sessions are not accessible in carrier wave uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, spree

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:

   storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    byebug
    session[:user_email_id]

  end

  def get_time
    @time = Time.now
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
   def extension_whitelist
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

In the above store_dir method, it expects a string to be returned. So I am trying give the string as the current users email id. Which is already set in some other controller and it is accessible in other controllers. Is there anything I am missing related to carrier wave?

Even `spree_current_user` is not accessible in this AvatarUploader

Answer (score 0):

When we uses "session[xx]" in controller, that because controller has a method called "session", which returns the user's session. I believed neither AvatarUploader or CarrierWave::Uploader::Base has this session method, that's why you can not call 'session[xxx]' in them.

Comment: can you please suggest some solution in which I can use sessions there?

Comment: use "model" method to get what you want

Comment: The model variable points to the instance object the uploader is attached to.

Comment: Unfortuantely I need to get the user email, So the query would be like this to `StudioOrder.find_by(id: spree_current_user.id).email` even spree_current_user is not accessible in that uploader

Comment: The uploader must be have some kind of connection with the user who's email you want  to get, right?  Follow the connection.